# MYSQL LEFT JOIN is not working as expected not showing all rows from left table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following structure for `form_meta`

[image]

and `entry_meta`

[image]

I am running this query

```sql
SELECT 
    sequence AS sequence,
    meta_label AS label,
    results AS results,
    entry_id
FROM
    `form_meta`
        LEFT JOIN
    `entry_meta` ON form_meta.id = entry_meta.form_meta_id
WHERE
    `form_meta`.`form_id` = 10
        AND is_active = 1
```

But, I am getting 4 rows as result. I am looking for 5 rows as `form_meta` is having 5 rows, last row must be empty.

Comment: please don't post images when adding data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: There is no problem in your query. You should find the problem on how you process the result of the query, debug your php code

Comment: Since your form_meta_id matches with 4 elements in other table, that's you might be getting only 4 rows in final result.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use proper table aliases?

```
SELECT 
    fm.sequence AS sequence,
    fm.meta_label AS label,
    em.results AS results,
    em.entry_id
FROM form_meta fm
LEFT JOIN entry_meta em ON fm.id = em.form_meta_id
WHERE fm.form_id = 10 AND fm.is_active = 1;
```